# Heisig Book 2 spreadsheet for anyone who wants it

Tags: discussion

This isn't a question or a discussion point, it's just about a possible learning aid I've made that might be of interest to people who use this site.

I initially used the Heisig system for remembering kanji when I first started out learning kanji.

As one does, I used flashcards and other systems to help me along in my study. Since there are 2000 or so kanji to learn, this is a lot of data entry (assuming one uses some kind of online flashcards or computer based learning aid).

I found that I could go online and get a lot of pre-made resources for the first Heisig book (which focuses on how to write only), which helped to get over the arduous task of inputting all the kanji.

However, when I got to book two (which focuses on on-yomi only), I found that online resources dropped off sharply. At the time, I could not find a single online database of the readings.

So I made my own. As I went along, I entered in all the readings and other notes into a spreadsheet, and then later I could take that spreadsheet and convert it into various flashcard systems or whatever else.

Now, it's many years later and I don't use the Heisig system at all anymore (and I have some criticisms of it...). However, I noticed from being here on this list that other people still do.

So, maybe there are already places online where one can get an entire list of the kanji as they are presented in Heisig's second book. I don't know, I haven't really checked and can't really be bothered to. But I'm pretty sure the availability of Heisig 1 related resources vastly outnumbering the Heisig 2 resources is still true.

In any case, it seemed a waste to me to just delete the file just 'cause I don't need it (it represents a *lot* of work). One advantage of this file is that since it's just a straight up spreadsheet, you can convert it fairly easily into whatever format you want. There might be existing flashcards for Heisig Book 2, but they might be bound to one format or another.

So if anyone wants a spreadsheet (in OpenOffice/LibreOffice .ods format) version of Heisig's book 2, let me know and I'll happily give it to you. Ideally, it would be great if it got passed on and utilized by anyone and everyone who wanted to make flashcards or whatever else.

What is in the spreadsheet is a list of all the kanji in Heisig's book two, ordered as they are in the book, with all the readings presented, numbered, and other stuff that might have mattered when I was using it.

I'm fairly sure it is accurate, but I can't promise there isn't a typo or something in there somewhere. Even if there are a couple of errors, it's a hell of a leg up if you need to have the list.

Anyway, if anyone wants it, write an answer here or something and we'll work out how to get it to you.

Comment: Is there some way to put it in a file-and-forget public location, like a shared Google Docs file or something?  I'm worried this is a time-sensitive offer, and it'd be a shame for someone trying to learn in the future to miss out on something like this.

Comment: I'm willing to put it online somewhere, but not if it's tied to my own Google docs account. Just because I tend to be pretty aggressive about file organization and cleaning things I don't need, so I wouldn't be a reliable repository. If anyone has a suggestion for where I could leave it so it's likely to be found, that would be great.

Comment: @Troyen: I've made the file available on Dropbox. Please download it and check it out. Note I ordered things by JLPT level, which may not suit your needs, but it could be reordered with just a little tweaking. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3668332/Heisig_Book_2.ods Note to anyone who might want this file: it won't be there indefinitely, so please download it soon if you want it. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: c. 11/2020 the link doen't seem to be working

Comment: @MH, try https://www.dropbox.com/s/km3i4ezm6lqh2nq/Heisig_Book_2.ods?dl=0

Comment: Great! Thank you for the link: nice chart, link functions prefectly! Thank you / どうもありがとうございます  :)